# Facebook security warning in google search results

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-like, google-search

We launched a new site recently and, as part of it, we included the Facebook like box HTML5 code.  Now when we search for the site on google, right under the title and url, we get the following message:

> SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your
>   password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Center
>   for more ...

Does anyone know what's causing this?  I'm guessing it's something to do with the Facebook like box we included, but can't seem to find any information or a fix.

It doesn't appear if you search for the site in Bing or Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

From this discussion: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/qs7CfaqTgpU

> That is not a malware warning, it does not indicate anything
>   malicious.  That is a warning from Facebook basically to you regards
>   the way you are connecting to Facebook.  There is going to be a gadget
>   on your blog where you connect to Facebook.  No idea why it would
>   suddenly start generating the warning -- best guess would be Facebook
>   has rolled out a security change to their API and the code being used
>   in that gadget has not been updated to work with the new API

Seems like you Facebook like box is not using the newest API available. Have you got the code from Facebook developer's site?

**Edit:**

In addition, in your link someone told to the asker to remove this code from this site, maybe you also have it:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "// connect . facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code used is the latest from this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages .  Do you think we just have to wait for them to release updated code?

Comment: "The Like Box is a special version of the Like Button designed ** only for Facebook Pages **."
First of all you should use the simple like button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Comment: Hi again, I've taken the latest html 5 code from the developers site.  I did have the code in the script tags on the page, but taking it out causes the box not to work unfortunately.  I've swapped out the html 5 version for the iframe version so we're not using any javascript, hopefully this will sort it out.  Thanks for your help.